# No logro modificar la información del perfil actual JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Deseo crear un método para modificar el perfil de la sesión actual pero no logro hacerlo, me devuelve la pantalla con los datos sin aplicar la modificación. Este es el método:

```
public void putUser() {
    Usuarios u = new Usuarios();
    u.setEmail(bean.getEmail());
    u.setNombre(bean.getNombre());
    u.setApellidos(bean.getApellidos());
    u.setFechanac(bean.getFechanac());
    u.setTarjeta(bean.getTarjeta());
    u.setMovil(bean.getMovil());
    u.setPassword(bean.getPassword());

    target2.path("{email}")
            .resolveTemplate("email", bean.getEmail())
            .request()
            .put(Entity.entity(u,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
}
```

Donde Bean es de tipo UserBacking Bean, dejo la clase:

```
package client;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBackingBean implements Serializable{

    String nombre;
    String email;
    String password;
    String fechanac;
    String nombregrupo;
    String apellidos;
    String tarjeta;
    String confirmPassword;
    String movil;

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public String getTarjeta() {
        return tarjeta;
    }

    public void setTarjeta(String tarjeta) {
        this.tarjeta = tarjeta;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getMovil() {
        return movil;
    }

    public void setMovil(String movil) {
        this.movil = movil;
    }


    public String getNombregrupo() {
        return nombregrupo;
    }

    public void setNombregrupo(String nombregrupo) {
        this.nombregrupo = nombregrupo;
    }

    public String getFechanac() {
        return fechanac;
    }

    public void setFechanac(String fechanac) {
        this.fechanac = fechanac;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: public void putUser() {
         Usuarios u = new Usuarios();
         u.setEmail(bean.getEmail());
         u.setNombre(bean.getNombre());
         u.setApellidos(bean.getApellidos());
         u.setFechanac(bean.getFechanac());
         u.setTarjeta(bean.getTarjeta());
         u.setMovil(bean.getMovil());
         u.setPassword(bean.getPassword());
   
         
         target2.path("{email}").resolveTemplate("email", bean.getEmail()).request()
                 .put(Entity.entity(u,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
     }

Comment: Arriba no se ve entero

Comment: He revisado que la ruta de target sea correcta, ya que la utilizo en varios métodos que me funcionan